# About Passive voice of perception verb

Tags: passive-voice, verbs-of-perception

Could I ask you about 'Passive voice of perception verb'?

There is a sentence, here.

> "'I saw him cross the street.".

This sentence is elliptical "to-infinitive".
Which passive construction  would be correct in this sentence?

> "He **was seen cross** the street"

or

> "He **was seen *to* cross** the street" ?

As the grammar book says, "He **was seen *to* cross** the street" is correct.

But Americans  say that "He **was seen crossing** the street" is commonly used.

Could anyone explain me, do "He was seen **to** cross the street" and "He was seen **crossing** the street." mean the same?

---

There is a link of the forum. Could you watch this one?

http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/he-was-seen-to-cross-crossing-the-street.475171

I 'm confusing, now. Please give me a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the [discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/he-was-seen-to-cross-crossing-the-street.475171/) you linked to, I think user, brilliantpink, has a very good answer:

> The construction "to be seen to do something" is indeed correct, but
>   uncommon. It means exactly the same as "to be seen doing something". 
>   The only difference, in my opinion, is that "to be seen to" puts the
>   emphasis on the seeing rather than the action being done. It might be
>   used in a legal case, or another situation where there is a question
>   of whether the person actually 'crossed the street' or not, or whether
>   they are guilty of some other act that followed. "Well, he was seen to
>   cross the street" (someone says they saw him, so we know he must have
>   crossed the street, but we don't know what he did after that).
>
> Important: This construction is used only in the passive, and perhaps
>   that is why it strikes people as odd. Not "I saw him to cross the
>   street" but only "He was seen to..."

---

Another aspect that is touched on in that discussion is when reading "He was seen **to cross** the street", I infer a sense that "He" has a habit of crossing the street.

It resembles the turn of phrase, "He is known to...", which is used to describe a characteristic or habit of someone. For example:

- He is known to smoke two packs a day.
- He is known to be afraid of dogs.
- He was known to bring flowers to his mother weekly.
- The club was known to exclude people of color.

---

Technically, the two sentences could mean the same thing. However, I assume that if the speaker chooses to use the more unnatural phrasing, they mean to imply something extra.